# Jquery is not loading / dropdown box

Tags: jquery, html

Hey guys im workin right now on a new website and i have some problems with it .

The first one is , if i put `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`at the end of the script is the navigation with fades in and out not working anymore. if im putting the script at the top , so at the head part is the second navigation working but the dropwdown menu at the first navigation on the top is not working anymore.

right now is it at the head part and i have this error message `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`[test site](http://www.awesom-media.de/design/about-us.html)

and the next thing is that i would like to have at the second navigation also a dropwdown menue, but i dont know how to get it. if im copying the code from the first one is it not working anymore.

Comment: You have to declare jQuery before you can use it in your javascript. If you stick `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` after your code controlling the fade animations they won't work as they can't access the jQuery code which make them work. To ensure this doesn't happen always ensure that jQuery is declared on your page before any of your own javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Few errors I can see
1.

```
Error: TypeError: jQuery(...).fitVids is not a function
Source File: http://www.awesom-media.de/design/js/scripts.js
Line: 364
```

Looks like you want to use [FItVids.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js) but you haven't imported it

2

```
Error: ReferenceError: ddsmoothmenu is not defined
Source File: http://www.awesom-media.de/design/js/scripts.js
Line: 406
```

Not sure if its from a plugin or self defined.
Also as judder mentioned, import jQuery at top or bottom but make sure you to do it before using it.